# Newtonsoft.Json MVC: how customize DTO error message for failed json validation

Tags: c#, json, .net, api, json.net

I have an API project on [.NET Core 3.1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1) configured to use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

`Startup.cs`

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // [...]

    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

    // [...]
}
```

`Data.cs`

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MyNS
{
    [JsonObject]
    public class MyData
    {
        [JsonProperty("query", Required=Required.Always)]
        public Query Query { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("limit")]
        public int Limit { get; set; }
    }

    public class Query
    {
        [JsonProperty("props", Required=Required.Always)]
        public List<Prop> Props { get; set; }
    }

    public class Prop
    {
        // Allowed values should be only ("key1" and "key2"). Other strings or types should fail validation
        [JsonProperty("key", Required = Required.Always)]
        public string Key { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("value", Required = Required.Always)]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`MyController.cs`

```cs
// [...]
[Route("test")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> Test(MyData data)
{
    return Json(data);
}
// [...]
```

If the request json body fails the validation, a preconfigured error message with a 400 status is returned to the client:

`REQUEST`

```json
POST /test
{
  "query": {
    "props": [
      {
        "key": "k1",
        "value": "v1"
      }
    ]
  },
  "limit": "wrong"
}
```

`RESPONSE`

```json
{
    "errors": {
        "limit": [
            "Could not convert string to integer: wrong. Path 'limit', line 10, position 18."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|2778ea7e-4dff69c960e985d5."
}
```

I would like to customize the errore response with a DTO of my choice, for example: 
`RESPONSE`

```json
"success": false,
"error": "First validation error"
```

How can I configure `Newtonsoft.Json` to use a custom DTO for validation errors?

Answer (score 0):

Found a possible solution:

`Startup.cs`

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => { })
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options => {
        options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
        {
            string errorMessage = "Validation error";

            foreach (var key in context.ModelState.Keys)
            {
                if (context.ModelState[key].Errors.Count > 0)
                {
                    errorMessage = string.Format("Json property '{0}': {1}", key, context.ModelState[key].Errors[0].ErrorMessage);
                    break;
                }
            }

            int statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

            var dto = new
            {
                success = false,
                error = errorMessage
            };

            return new JsonResult(dto) { StatusCode = statusCode };
        };
    });
}
```